# How to resolve mkdir invalid argument error in Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I have added the .box, When I run the command "`vagrant up`" I am getting the following error, I am working on windows OS. How to resolve the error any suggestions?

```
E:\Test_Prj\Vagrant_05Aug2014>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'test-phil'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: Vagrant_05Aug2014_default_1407248787170_35925
==> default: Destroying VM and associated drives...
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `mkdir': Invalid argument - E:/
Test_Prj/Vagrant_05Aug2014/file: (Errno::EINVAL)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `fu_mkdir'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:219:in `block (2 levels) in m
kdir_p'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `reverse_each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `block in mkdir_p'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `mkdir_p'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/pathname.rb:556:in `mkpath'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced
_folders.rb:56:in `block (2 levels) in call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced
_folders.rb:41:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced
_folders.rb:41:in `block in call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced
_folders.rb:40:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced
_folders.rb:40:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced
_folder_cleanup.rb:28:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/plugins/synced_folders/nfs/action
_cleanup.rb:19:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/acti
on/prepare_nfs_valid_ids.rb:12:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle
_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:160:in `handle'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle
_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:42:in `block in call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:434:in
 `lock'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle
_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:41:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/acti
on/prepare_forwarded_port_collision_params.rb:30:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/env_se
t.rb:19:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provis
ion.rb:80:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/acti
on/clear_forwarded_ports.rb:15:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/acti
on/set_name.rb:50:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/acti
on/clean_machine_folder.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/acti
on/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:i
n `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116
:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:i
n `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `b
usy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:i
n `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.r
b:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:i
n `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116
:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:i
n `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `b
usy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:i
n `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.r
b:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:i
n `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116
:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:i
n `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `b
usy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:i
n `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.r
b:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_ch
eck_outdated.rb:36:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config
_validate.rb:25:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/acti
on/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:i
n `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/acti
on/match_mac_address.rb:16:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/acti
on/import.rb:32:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/acti
on/customize.rb:40:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/acti
on/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:i
n `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116
:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:i
n `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `b
usy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:i
n `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.r
b:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config
_validate.rb:25:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:i
n `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle
_box.rb:56:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:i
n `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116
:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:i
n `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `b
usy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:i
n `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.r
b:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/acti
on/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:i
n `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116
:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:i
n `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `b
usy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:i
n `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:196:in `ac
tion_raw'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:173:in `bl
ock in action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:434:in
 `lock'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:161:in `ca
ll'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:161:in `ac
tion'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in
 `block (2 levels) in run'
```

Comment: I assume your user has write permissions in the directory? To help troubleshoot it, you could try running "vagrant up --debug" to give a more detailed startup log. (Ref: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/other/debugging.html)

Comment: . Box file is created in Ubuntu os  and now I am trying to install / set it up on Windows. Will that creates a problem? If yes suggest me any solution please.

Comment: In general you should be able to create a Vagrant configuration that works on both Ubuntu and Windows as host OS. It may take some adjustments to work properly on Windows. If you can post your Vagrantfile here, someone might be able to spot the problem.

Comment: Also I will try with debug mode.

Comment: Sure will post the configuration files

Comment: My system has avast Antivirus will that creates an issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error:

```
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `mkdir': Invalid argument - C:/Users/atexo/WORKSPACE/lt_api/.vagrant/machines/default/C: (Errno::EINVAL)
```

I added the line:

```
ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = 'virtualbox'
```

just before the line:

```
vagrantKey = "#{vagrant_dot}/machines/default/#{ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER']}/private_key"
```

And everything works

Comment: which file need to put it?